# How to Improve OCR on image with text in different colors and fonts?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, google-vision

I'm using the [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to extract the text from some pictures, however, I have been trying to improve the accuracy (confidence) of the results with no luck.

every time I change the image from the original I lose accuracy in detecting some characters.

I have isolated the issue to have multiple colors for different words with can be seen that words in red for example have incorrect results more often than the other words.

Example:

some variations on the image from gray scale or b&w

[image: Original Image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What ideas can I try to make this work better, specifically changing the colors of text to a uniform color or just black on a white background since most algorithms expect that?

some ideas I already tried, also some thresholding.

```
dimg = ImageOps.grayscale(im)
cimg = ImageOps.invert(dimg)

contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(dimg)
eimg = contrast.enhance(1)

sharp = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(dimg)
eimg = sharp.enhance(1)
```

Comment: why is the red text, and partly also the green text, blurred when compared to the white text?

Comment: Great question @WalterTross, that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. it makes sense though that this happens because the player name has different shades of color so some of it goes white and some of it goes to black when you binarize it. and the main question would how to find a good threshold where all the text goes to black

Comment: Is the quality of the source images really this poor?

Comment: Such a great question - very topical!

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer a butcher's solution, potentially a nightmare to maintain.

In my own, very limited scenario, it worked like a charm where several other OCR engines either failed or had unacceptable running times.

My prerequisites:

- I knew exactly in which area of the screen the text was going to go.
- I knew exactly which fonts and colors were going to be used.
- the text was semitransparent, so the underlying image interfered, and it was a variable image to boot.
- I could not detect reliably text changes to average frames and reduce the interference.

What I did:
 - I measured the kerning width of each character. I only had A-Za-z0-9 and a bunch of punctuation characters to worry about.
 - The program would start at position (0,0), measure the average color to determine the color, then access the whole set of bitmaps generated from characters in all available fonts in that color. Then it would determine which rectangle was closest to the corresponding rectangle on the screen, and advance to the next one.

(Months later, requiring more performances, I added a varying probability matrix to test first the most likely characters).

In the end, the resulting C program was able to read the subtitles out of the video stream with 100% accuracy in real time.

Answer (score 1):

You tried almost every standard step. I would advise you to try some PIL built-in filters like sharpness filter. Apply sharpness and contrast on the RGB image, then binarise it. Perhaps use Image.split() and Image.merge() to binarise each colour separately and then bring them back together.
Or convert your image to YUV and then use just Y channel for further processing.
Also, if you do not have a monochrome background consider performing some background substraction.

What tesseract likes when detecting scanned text is removed frames, so you can try to destroy as much of non character space from the image. (You might need to keep the picture size though, so you should replace it with white colour). Tesseract also likes straight lines. So some deskewing might be in order if your text is recorded at an angle. Tesseract also sometimes gives better results if you resize the image to twice its original size.

I suspect that Google Vision uses tesseract, or portions of it, but what other preprocessing it does for you I have no idea. So some of my advices here might actually be implemented already and doing them would be unnecessary and repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

I need a little more context on this.

1. How many calls are you going to do to the Google Vision API? If you are doing this throughout a whole stream, you'd probably need to get a paid subscription.
2. What are you going to do with this data? How accurate does the OCR need to be?
3. Assuming you get this snapshot from another's twitch stream, dealing with the streamer's video compression and network connectivity, you're going to get pretty blurry snapshot, so OCR is going to be pretty tough.

The image is far too blurry because of video compression, so even preprocessing the image to improve quality may not get the image quality high enough for accurate OCR. If you are set on OCR, one approach you could try:

1. Binarize the image to get the non-red text in white and background black as in your binarized image:

   ```
   from PIL import Image

   def binarize_image(im, threshold):
   """Binarize an image."""
       image = im.convert('L')  # convert image to monochrome
       bin_im = image.point(lambda p: p > threshold and 255)
       return bin_im

   im = Image.open("game_text.JPG")
   binarized = binarize_image(im, 100)
   ```

[image]

2. Extract only the red text values with a filter, then binarize it:

   ```
   import cv2
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

   lower = [15, 15, 100]
   upper = [50, 60, 200]

   lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
   upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

   mask = cv2.inRange(im, lower, upper)
   red_binarized = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask = mask)

   plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(red_binarized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
   plt.show()
   ```

However, even with this filtering, it still doesn't extract red well.

[image]

[image]

3. Add images obtained in (1.) and (2.).

   ```
   combined_image = binarized + red_binarized
   ```

[image]

4. Do OCR on (3.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pre-process the image more than once, and use a `bitwise_or` operation to combine the results. To extract the colors, you could use

```
import cv2
boundaries = [      #BGR colorspace for opencv, *not* RGB
    ([15, 15, 100], [50, 60, 200]),    #red
    ([85, 30, 2], [220, 90, 50]),      #blue
    ([25, 145, 190], [65, 175, 250]),  #yellow
]

for (low, high) in boundaries:
    low = np.array(low, dtype = "uint8")
    high = np.array(high, dtype = "uint8")

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
    # the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, low, high)
    bitWise = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    #now here is the image masked with the specific color boundary...
```

Once you have the masked image, you can do another `bitwise_or` operation on your to-be "final" image, essentially adding this mask to it.

but this specific implementation requires opencv, however the same principle applies for other image packages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution but it may drive to something better.

By converting your data from BGR (or RGB) to CIE-La*b* you can process a grayscale image as the weighted sum of the colour channels a* and b*.
This grayscale image will enhance colour regions of the text.
But adapting the threshold you can from this grayscale image segment the coloured word in your original image and get the other words from the a L channel thresholding.
A bitwise and operator should be enough to merge to two segmentation image.

If you can have an image with a better contrast a very last step could be a filling based on the contours.
For that take a look to `RETR_FLOODFILL` of the function 'cv2.findContours'. 
Any other hole filing function from other package may also fit for that purpose.

Here is a code that show the first part of my idea.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

I = cv2.UMat(cv2.imread('/home/smile/QSKN.png',cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR))

Lab = cv2.cvtColor(I,cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)

L,a,b = cv2.split(Lab)

Ig = cv2.addWeighted(cv2.UMat(a),0.5,cv2.UMat(b),0.5,0,dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

Ig = cv2.normalize(Ig,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)


#k = np.ones((3,3),np.float32)
#k[2,2] = 0
#k*=-1
#
#Ig = cv2.filter2D(Ig,cv2.CV_32F,k)
#Ig = cv2.absdiff(Ig,0)
#Ig = cv2.normalize(Ig,None,0.,255.,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)



_, Ib = cv2.threshold(Ig,0.,255.,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, Lb = cv2.threshold(cv2.UMat(L),0.,255.,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

_, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)

ax[0,0].imshow(Ig.get(),cmap='gray')
ax[0,1].imshow(L,cmap='gray')
ax[1,0].imshow(Ib.get(),cmap='gray')
ax[1,1].imshow(Lb.get(),cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import selem
from skimage.filters import rank, threshold_otsu
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from PIL import ImageGrab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def preprocessing(image, strelem, s0=30, s1=30, p0=.3, p1=1.):
    image = rank.mean_bilateral(image, strelem, s0=s0, s1=s1)
    condition = (lambda x: x>threshold_otsu(x))(rank.maximum(image, strelem))
    normalize_image = rank.autolevel_percentile(image, strelem, p0=p0, p1=p1)
    return np.where(condition, normalize_image, 0)

#Grab image from clipboard
image = np.array(ImageGrab.grabclipboard())
sel = selem.disk(4)
a = sum([img_as_float(preprocessing(image[:, :, x], sel, p0=0.3)) for x in range(3)])/3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[1].imshow(rank.autolevel_percentile(a, sel, p0=.4))
```

This is my code for clearing text from noise and creating uniform brightness for characters.
With minor modifications, I used it to solve your problem.

[image]